# Maintain a PHP session_start() with cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a PHP code which starts a session using `session_start()`. Well, after a user is logged in, is brought to profile.php, which shows that user info. But when the user reloads the page, the session is gone. Is there any way I can maintain it an hour for example? I've tried cookies but I don't know how to tell PHP that the session is started already. Thanks!

Profile.php code for cookies and session start:

```
if(isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['session'])){ 
     session_start();
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Login code:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['pass']  = $password;
header('Location: ../profile.php');
setcookie("session","1",time()+3600,"/");
```

Code which checks the session:

```
if($_SESSION['pass'] == $tableArray[0]['password']) {
    $username = $tableArray[0]['name'];
    $avatar = $tableArray[0]['avatar'];
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

I was calling session_destroy() on here:

```
<li><a href=<?php session_destroy(); echo "index.php"?>>Logout</a></li>
```

And forgot PHP runs before HTML :P that was the problem!

Comment: Is your session name 'session'? You didn't set its name to 'session' using `session_name('session')` in your login code. By default the session name (and cookie name) is `PHPSESSID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you're not calling session_start() again or
- you're calling session_destroy(); anywhere in file

Comment: I only call `session_destroy();` on `<li><a href=<?php session_destroy(); echo "index.php"?>>Logout</a></li>`

Comment: then you call it ALWAYS. PHP is executed on the server, befor the user even see the link :-)

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking I found the solution for this.

One thing is already specified change save path string else change the permission of the directory where your session is being stored.

I did this it worked for me.

If your session is stored in session dir then do this:

```
chmod 777 session/
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not calling `session_start()` again on `profile.php`.

You must call `session_start()` on every script that will access the session data.

**UPDATE after code posted**

Instead of checking for the presence of the session cookie, instead do something like:

```
// Start the session first
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  // user is already logged in
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: that wasn't the problem, it was I was calling session_destroy(); and forgot PHP code runs before HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `session.use_cookies` to be on (in php.ini/.htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You have to say `session_start()` at the top of **every** script that needs to know the session data.

The session cookie is really none of your concern, you should consider that an "implementation detail". (The cookie will usually live in the user's browser until the browser exits.)

Comment: I just tried it, but every time the page is reloaded it doesn't works. Edited with the code to check the session

Comment: No no, don't say `isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['session']))` -- you have no idea what the session cookie is called! Stop thinking about cookies, just think in terms of sessions. Forget that there are cookies altogether.