# Php setcookie not working on Android phones

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I have the following code where I set cookies normally. It was working fine until the new `SameSite` update from chrome. It stopped working. I've added the `SameSite` as you can see but a few users who use `Chrome` on `Android` are having issues logging in. I did some logging to try and figure out why users couldn't log in and it seems like some users who use older versions of android and chrome are unable to login because the following code apparently doesn't work for them.

```
$expire = time() + 4 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; // Making the cookie live for 4 weeks
$en_string = "some string";
setcookie("username", $en_string, $expire, "/; SameSite=None; Secure");
setcookie("login_key", "1", $expire, "/; SameSite=None; Secure");
```

I am running `Php5 5.6.30` on `apache` and `CentOS`. Any help what should I change. The response from `apache_response_headers()` is

```
Array
(
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.32    
    [Accept] => application/json
    [Set-Cookie] => username=some string; expires=Fri, 13-Nov-2020 05:20:25 GMT; Max-Age=2419200; path=/;samesite=strict
    [Expires] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [Cache-Control] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    [Pragma] => no-cache
)
```

Comment: That is not how `setcookie` is supposed to be used. What’s the actual HTTP header output by this?

Comment: Added response to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same problem in php 5.7.4. The one difference I see is that when the first routine I can uses setcookie, it works. Then I include another file and do another setcookie and it fails. If I make sure all the cookies get set in the same routine, that's a workaround. But this is clearly a fairly deep bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have and where in your code usages of `session_start()` and/or `header()` functions. They might invoke an issue around cookies.

Also see these answers:

- [Maintain a PHP session_start() with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747706/maintain-a-php-session-start-with-cookies)
- [PHP – setcookie() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662580/php-setcookie-not-working)
- [Android webview cookie returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235489/android-webview-cookie-returns-null)

NB! Cookies might be disabled in your mobile browser.
To enable it (for example in Chrome):

- At the top right, tap "More" and then "Settings".
- Tap "Site settings" and then "Cookies".
- Turn Cookies on or off.